# ReactJS - setState() not reflecting change immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

My code is as follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counter : 0
        }
    }


    increment() {
        const { counter } = this.state;
        this.setState({counter : counter+1 });
        console.log(counter);
    }


    render() {
        const { counter} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> {counter} </h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.increment()}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

I have a simple h1 and a button. The behavior of the program should be that when I click the button the value of the counter should increment by 1 (on both the webpage and the console since I am printing the value of counter in console also). The problem is that when I click the button the value changes from 0 to 1 on my webpage but in my console I still see the value of counter as 0 (instead of 1), when I click the button second time, the value changes from 1 to 2 on my webpage but in my console, the value changes from 0 to 1 (instead of 2). Can someone please tell me whats going on ?

Comment: So what should I do to get my desired output ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Is there any other way without using the prevCounter ?

Comment: There was a mistake in my first comment, following is the correct way to update the state in your case: `this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }), () => console.log(counter));`

Comment: Both answers are correct with regards to the asynchronous nature of `setState`. But in your case here, even if it were fully synchronous, you would log the *old* value simple because of the initial destructuring assignment. With `state.counter` being a scalar value, you have actually copied that value into the `counter` variable. Any changes to `state.counter` afterwards would not be reflected. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vf1kwnuc/

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState()` is a asynchronous function, so happens in the background whilst it moves to the next line.
To run code after setState(), you need a callback - so in your example it would be:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }), () => console.log(counter)); // the console.log() will only run after the setState is finished!
```

Its easy to forget its asynchronous because, it often happens so fast you can `console.log()` immediately afterwards and the state has changed!

Answer (score 0):

setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the [documentation of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#:%7E:text=setState()%20does%20not%20always%20immediately%20update%20the%20component).

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

You can use setState callback to find the immediate changes or you can use `componentDidUpdate`

```
this.setState({ counter : counter+1 }, newState => {
   console.log(newState.counter)
});
```

OR

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log(this.state) // New State
  console.log(prevState) // Previous State
  if (this.state.counter !== prevState.counter) {
    // counter changed
  }
}
```